# NSTableView Drop App File, Whats Going Wrong?

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, nsdragginginfo

I have the following code to support dropping an app file into a table view. The problem is that I don't even see the green + when I drag and drop. I think it has something to do with the `registerForDraggedTypes:` but I'm not sure. I've tried many tutorials and none have worked for me.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
[apps registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"app"]];    
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes         toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard
{
return YES;
}
- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView*)tv validateDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedRow:(int)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)op
{
return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info
          row:(int)row dropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)operation
{
return YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`registerForDraggedTypes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW137) isn't looking for an array of file extensions; it takes an array of [uniform type identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Types_for_Standard_Data_Mac_OS_X_10.6_and_later_). If you want to accept filenames, use the `NSFilenamesPboardType`:

```
 [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];
```

Then, to only accept `.app` files, check the extension and return YES from `tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:`, getting the appropriate information from the [`NSDraggingInfo` and its pasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000331).

Comment: For some reason I'm still not seeing the green +. What could be causing this?

Comment: Check the obvious: is your IBOutlet for the table view hooked up? Is the table view delegate connected? Does a breakpoint or NSLog in `acceptDrop` get hit?

Comment: It was all hooked up but still not working. To get it to work I used your suggestion but put it in an invisible NSView on top of the table view.